# Modifying XML output

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I have generated the XML in the following manner, except for the tag I bordered in red.

[image]

> How can I add the following line marked red to the `Accounts` tag:
>   ***ba.cbbh.crr.retail*** so that it looks as indicated in the photo above?
>   (Now it looks like [this](http://oi68.tinypic.com/biroed.jpg))
>
> Consider that I have to avoid XML syntax errors, such as blank space but retain blank space after Accounts.
>
> (`<Accounts xmlns="ba.cbbh.crr.retailba.cbbh.crr.retail">`)

[I tried this but nothing changes...](http://oi66.tinypic.com/14ujmz5.jpg)

```
DECLARED ALL...

SET @ACCOUNTTYPE = 'T';

SET @kodBanke = ( SELECT vrednost FROM dbini WHERE IDENT = 'KOD' AND SECTION = 'PP' );
SET @XML_info = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
SET @xmlnsDodatak =  'ba.cbbh.crr.retail';



IF (@tabelaTipaRacuna = 'istdev')
BEGIN
SELECT @SQL =  'WITH Ent_Posta
            AS
        (
           SELECT e.naziv,p.posta,e.sifra
            FROM entitet AS e
          INNER JOIN poste AS p ON e.sifra = p.entitet
        )

           SELECT [dbo].[brojracuna](' + @kodBanke + ',i.partija) AS ''AccountNo/BBAN'',
           [dbo].[GENERATEIBAN](i.partija) AS ''AccountNo/IBAN'', 
           ' + '''D''' + ' AS ''AccountType'',
           (a.ime + ''('' + a.roditel + '')''  + a.prezime) AS ''Name'',
           a.embg AS ''UID'',
       CASE status 
       WHEN 2 THEN ''A'' 
       WHEN 4 THEN ''B''
       WHEN 8 THEN ''U''
  END AS ''Status'',
  c.sifra AS ''Territory'',
  ' + @kodBanke + ' as ''ID_Bank'',
  CONVERT(DATETIME,' + 'i.dotvoranje' + ',120) AS ''OpeningDate'',
  ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME,' + '1' + ',120),'''') AS ''ClosingDate''
 FROM adresar AS a
  INNER JOIN' + QUOTENAME(@tabelaTipaRacuna) + ' AS i 
      ON a.embg = i.embg
        INNER JOIN Ent_Posta as c
        ON a.postbroj = c.posta 
        FOR XML PATH(''Account''), ROOT(''Accounts'')'

         SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '''<Accounts>''', '''<Accounts xmlns="' + @xmlnsDodatak + '">''')
         SELECT @SQL
         EXEC(@SQL)
```

---

**Solution**:

This is what worked for me...

```
 ...'WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT ''ba.cbbh.crr.retail''), Ent_Posta
            AS
        (
           SELECT e.naziv,p.posta,e.sifra
            FROM entitet AS e
          INNER JOIN poste AS p ON e.sifra = p.entitet
        )...



... INNER JOIN Ent_Posta as c
    ON a.postbroj = c.posta 
    FOR XML PATH(''Account''), ROOT(''Accounts'')'...
```

***Edit:***

Now I want this:

[image]

After researching a bit I figured out it should look something like this:

```
...SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ''<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>''' + ''

         'WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT ''ba.cbbh.crr.retail''), Ent_Posta
            AS
        (
           SELECT e.naziv,p.posta,e.sifra
            FROM entitet AS e
          INNER JOIN poste AS p ON e.sifra = p.entitet
        ) ...
```

Apparently, it won't work.
What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a default namespace.  So follow this example:

> **Specifying Default Namespaces** Instead of declaring a namespace prefix, you can declare a default namespace by using a DEFAULT
>   keyword. In the FOR XML query, it will bind the default namespace to
>   XML nodes in the resulting XML. In the following example, the WITH
>   XMLNAMESPACES defines two namespace prefixes that are defined together
>   with a default namespace.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri1' as ns1,   
                    'uri2' as ns2,  
                    DEFAULT 'uri2')  
SELECT ProductID,   
      Name,  
      Color  
FROM Production.Product   
WHERE ProductID=316 or ProductID=317  
FOR XML RAW ('ns1:Product'), ROOT('ns2:root'), ELEMENTS
```

[Add Namespaces to Queries with WITH XMLNAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces)

You have a CTE, and to combine that with XMLNAMESPACES would look like:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri1' as ns1,   
                    'uri2' as ns2,  
                    DEFAULT 'uri2'),
q as
(
SELECT ProductID,   
      Name,  
      Color  
FROM Production.Product   
WHERE ProductID=316 or ProductID=317  
)
select *
from q
FOR XML RAW ('ns1:Product'), ROOT('ns2:root'), ELEMENTS
```

Comment: I am having troubles putting it inside a dynamic query...
You say it should look something like
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(''ba.cbbh.crr.retail'' AS Accounts)
...
FOR XML RAW('Accounts'),ELEMENTS '

Can you edit your answer and maybe be more case specific ?

Comment: And one more thing.
Shall I add *<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>* in the same manner?
Can you include this in your edit too?

Comment: The xml processing instruction is not normally necessary, and in any case would only be added when writing the XML to a file.

Comment: Can you take a look at my first comment, how can I add WITH XMLNAMESPACE inside the dynamic query?

Comment: @T_Dejan You must change this `SELECT @SQL =  'WITH Ent_Posta` to `SELECT @SQL =  'WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'younamespace'), Ent_Posta`. Why do you need this dynamically? Why the `REPLACE` at the end?

Comment: Shnugo, how can I add xml processing information to my query, take a look at the edit of my question.